# How to use OAuth2RestTemplate + Spring 4?

Tags: rest, spring-security, oauth-2.0, access-token, spring-4

I'm trying to understand how to use a OAuth2RestTemplate object to consume my OAuth2 secured REST service (which is running under a different project and let's assume also on a different server etc...)

f.e. my rest service is:

> https://localhost:8443/rest/api/user

-> Accessing this URL generates an error as I am not authenticated

To request a token I would go to:

> https://localhost:8443/rest/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=test&client_secret=test&username=**USERNAME**&password=**PASSWORD**

After I receive the token I can then connect to the REST API by using the following URL (example token inserted)

> https://localhost:8443/rest/api/user?access_token=**06**

I currently tried something with the following objects:

```
@EnableOAuth2Client
@Configuration
class MyConfig {

    @Value("${oauth.resource:https://localhost:8443}")
    private String baseUrl;
    @Value("${oauth.authorize:https://localhost:8443/rest/oauth/authorize}")
    private String authorizeUrl;
    @Value("${oauth.token:https://localhost:8443/rest/oauth/token}")
    private String tokenUrl;

    @Bean
    protected OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource() {

        ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resource = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();

        List scopes = new ArrayList<String>(2);
        scopes.add("write");
        scopes.add("read");
        resource.setAccessTokenUri(tokenUrl);
        resource.setClientId("test");
        resource.setClientSecret("test");
        resource.setGrantType("password");
        resource.setScope(scopes);

        resource.setUsername("test");
        resource.setPassword("test");

        return resource;
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate() {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
                .build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
        AccessTokenRequest atr = new DefaultAccessTokenRequest();
        OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource(), new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(atr));
        AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider provider = new AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider();
        provider.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
        restTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(provider);
        return restTemplate;
    }

}
```

I am tried to get token in controller like below.

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate;

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String TestForm() {
        System.out.println("Token : " + restTemplate.getAccessToken().getValue());
    }
}
```

But i got below exception

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/web] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.password.ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.password.ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:190)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173)
    at com.divyshivglobalinvestor.web.controller.PersonalLoanController.PersonalLoanForm(PersonalLoanController.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    at org.apache.coyote.AreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)bstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Th
```

From some blog I found that, if we need to grant password then, instead of ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails, it should be used AccessTokenRequest (which is a Map and is ephemeral). It would be great if someone can help me in getting accessToken. :)

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider` instead of `AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider` in `restTemplate` bean

Comment: Thanks for reply! Can you please give any working example