# Spring MVC and external Oauth2 server with Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a spring MVC application and a remote OAuth2 authorization server. Remote server should be used to log on to the web and mobile application and also to authorize micro services. OAuth2 server for authorization works and when I directly call path for obtain tokens, that request returns access and refresh token correctly.

My problem is that I cannot configure HttpSecurity in a class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in the web application, in order to enable logging form to stay in application and send request to remote OAuth2 using the password grunt type. So the `loginProcessingUrl()` should not be default `j_spring_security_check`, rather the path to the authorization server. I could not achieve that using `addFilterBefore()` in the http configuration.

My `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` class on the Oauth2 server application  in Spring Boot looks like this:

```
package com.mydomain.oauth2.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

     @Autowired
     @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
     private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

     @Autowired
     private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

     @Autowired
     private TokenStore tokenStore;

     @Bean
     public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
          return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
     }

     @Override
     public void configure( AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer)  throws Exception {
          oauthServer
              .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
              .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
              .allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
     }

     @Override
     public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
         clients
              .inMemory()
              .withClient("acme")
              .secret("acmesecret")
              .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600)
              .scopes("read", "write")
              .redirectUris("http://localhost:8080/login")
              .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
              .autoApprove(true)
              .resourceIds("resource");
      }

      @Override
      public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
              configurer.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
              configurer.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
              configurer.tokenStore(tokenStore);
      }
}
```

My `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class on a web application that was written in Spring not in Spring Boot looks like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientContext;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableOAuth2Client;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

import com.humanbizz.web.security.UserInfoTokenServices;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2ClientContextFilter oauth2ClientContextFilter;

    @Autowired
    OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
           .authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers("/login*", "/forgot-password*", "/signup**", "/signup/**", "/resources/**", "/403", "/storage/api/download/**", "/test/public/**").permitAll()
           .antMatchers("/user**").anonymous()
           .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
          .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
      .and()
         .exceptionHandling()
      .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("?")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
      .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
      .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
      .and()
            .addFilterBefore( myFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
     }

     private Filter myFilter() throws Exception{
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter myFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter("/login");
        OAuth2RestTemplate myTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(template(), oauth2ClientContext);
        teodeskFilter.setRestTemplate(myTemplate);    

        UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices("http://localhost:9000/user", "acme");
        tokenServices.setRestTemplate(myTemplate);
        teodeskFilter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);

        return myFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails template() {
        AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails details = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
        details.setClientId("acme");
        details.setClientSecret("acmesecret");
        details.setAccessTokenUri("http://localhost:9000/oauth/token"); details.setUserAuthorizationUri("http://localhost:9000/oauth/authorize");
        details.setGrantType("password");
        details.setScope(Arrays.asList("read"));

       return details;
   }

}
```

My question is how to configure filter to properly obtain token using form and password grunt type. Form is located on web application and should make request to remote auth server.The examples I have encountered are mostly related to Spring Boot or are solved by the fact that both Authorization Server and Resource Server were together on the same application.

Comment: The reason is that I did not find an example to implement it in this way, so I thought that way was not correct. Also, I would have to manually remember CookieCsrfTokenRepository and the principal user in Spring's UserDetails security class, and I believe that spring has the mechanisms that I can achieve through HttpSecurity configuration. For other grant types, there are examples, but for a grant type, I did not find any examples that would help me. Specifically for external OAut2 server, and login form on web application using password grant type

Comment: Password grant typ is made for a client, which ask its user for password itself, so it can send the password to the authorization server. You can't use Spring Security's form login, because it is made for complete authentication not only to collect the credentials. If you don't want a custom login page, you could always use implicit grant, where no custom login page is needed.

Comment: If I create my login controller and in this way I get a client token, then there is a problem where I can configure `AuthenticationManager` and `AuthenticationProvider`. So far they had a reference to the `UserDetailsService` that got the logged user from the database?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your last comment. Could you rephrase your question? Where do you need a `UserDetailsService`?

Comment: After getting the username and password with your custom login controller,
 you have to set it in [`ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/token/grant/password/ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails.html). This bean is not singleton, it is in the session. So `@EnableOAuth2Client` can use it.

Comment: In my login controller I obtain access token using `ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails` and `OAuth2AccessToken`, but I don't know how save that token in app and how to obtain and store Principal user?

Comment: If you use `EnableOAuth2Client` you don't need to call token endpoint manually. You have only  to declare a session.scoped `ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails`.After getting the username and password, you have to change it in  `ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails`.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722085/how-to-use-oauth2resttemplate-spring-4